# ajax calendar control not working in master page

Tags: asp.net

I have created a master page and i am using ajax calendar control for date. I have added ajax calendar control to date textbox. But when I run this, the calendar is not showing. When I click on the text box it is not showing the calendar. What is the problem? Please help.

Here is my code-

```
<td class="auto-style2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtdob" runat="server" Width="161px" CausesValidation="True" Height="19px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" > </asp:ScriptManager>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtdob_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtdob" Format="mm/dd/yyyy" >
    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
</td>
```

Comment: have u added script manager in your page?

Comment: yes. still i am getting the same problem

Comment: there is no problem in this html. remove the class="auto-style2" from td then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **ToolkitScriptManager** instead of **ScriptManager**

In format you have Format="mm/dd/yyyy"

> mm not valid month

Change it to

> Format="MM/dd/yyyy"

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtdob" runat="server"
              Width="161px" CausesValidation="True"
             Height="19px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">   
 </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtdob_CalendarExtender" runat="server"
                      Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtdob" 
                      Format="MM/dd/yyyy" >
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regist your ajaxcontrol tool kit

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/ajax/article.php/c19663/Getting-Started-with-the-ASPNET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit.htm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added AjaxContrlToolKit to Bin folder then Register your ajaxcontrol

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>
```